# Can i remove `vector` elements while iterating them using their pointers/references?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdvector

I have a struct that represents stat modifications on a character in a videogame, as well as a function that "exhausts" this buff for a turn/phase:

```cpp
typedef struct CharacterBuff {
    BuffTypeEnum buff_type;
    int value; // < 0 for nerfs, > 0 for buffs
    int phases; // < 0 for infinite phases
} CharacterBuff;

bool pass_phase(CharacterBuff* character_buff) {
    if (!character_buff) { return false; }
    if (character_buff->phases < 0) { return false; }
    --(character_buff->phases);
    return character_buff->phases <= 0;
}
```

I have a vector of these `CharacterBuff` structs that I loop through and use `pass_phase` on each of them, removing them if `pass_phase` returns true.
How do I do so in a safe manner?
Also if possible please critique the code for mistakes as well as better alternatives to what I'm doing.

I'm not knowledgeable about removing c++ vector elements while iterating through it as well as other vector algorithms, so I didn't try much and other answers I've searched don't use pointers as far as I notice.

Comment: You can use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). Personally, I would separate this `pass_phase` into two steps. One simply updates the `phases`, and the other returns whether it should be removed. The first can be applied in an ordinary range-based loop, the second can be handled with `std::remove_if`. And yes, you can turn a pointer or reference into an iterator. I don't think you really need that here. Note also that your logic with `temp_phases` is completely unnecessary, and adds pointless complexity.

Comment: `typedef struct CharacterBuff` -- The `typedef` is not necessary in C++.  Just plain `struct CharacterBuff`.  -- *I'm not knowledgeable about removing c++ vector elements while iterating through it* -- There is no harm in trying.  That's what any programmer would do -- write a simple `main` program, fill a vector with items, and see the results by trying what they are attempting to learn.

Comment: Another alternative is to have a `bool` member of `CharacterBuff` that denotes whether this object is alive or not.  Also, the logic you have in `pass_phase` is confusing to me in what is returned and the checking for `<=0`, depending on `phase`.   When does it ever return `true`?  Might as well have a simple `bool` member, and set it to `false` if you want that item erased, `true` if you want that item to stay.  Then a simple `erase-std::remove_if`, that erases all items with a `false` value.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that `std::remove_if` can use references, but not pointers. So I've modified my pass_phase to use a reference instead.

```cpp
bool pass_phase(CharacterBuff& character_buff) {
    if (character_buff.phases < 0) { return false; }
    --(character_buff.phases);
    return character_buff.phases <= 0;
}

void pass_phase_for_buffs(std::vector<CharacterBuff>& buffs) {
    buffs.erase(std::remove_if(buffs.begin(), buffs.end(), pass_phase), buffs.end());
}
```

Comment: *I've found out that std::remove_if can use references, but not pointers.* -- You could have simply dereferenced the pointer instead of changing the signature of your function.

Comment: [This uses pointers](https://godbolt.org/z/ehYb1P19Y).